# MarkLogic logs have brought attention to the requirement for Linux Huge Pages

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

MarkLogic logs highlighted the need for Huge Page space, as mentioned in the screenshot below.

> 2023-10-03 02:37:59.199 Info: Linux Huge Pages: detected 0, recommend
> 14176 to 94676

As per the MarkLogic recommendation ([view here](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/16/0/linux-huge-pages)), allocating 3/8 of the total physical memory, which amounts to 48GB for a system with 128GB of RAM, is advised. However, it's important to note that allocating this 48GB will significantly increase system boot time and lock it into memory.

Could you please recommend the ideal number of Huge Pages for a system with 128GB of physical memory?

Comment: IN addition to the clear response from Mads, digging into the article above  - and then onto the next one references will also being you here:  https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/group-level-cache-settings-based-on-ram

I think those three docs combined are a good read to help understand  huge pages and some other cache related items.

Answer (score 2):

The recommendation is what is logged and what the article states.

The idea is that HugePages is faster and more efficient memory access, and you would want to reserve at least enough for the MarkLogic caches to fit, and possibly a little more to be used for in-memory stands and other MarkLogic needs. That is why it gives you a range.

You can choose not to configure HugePages if you want. Things will still work.

If performance matters, then you may want to consider HugePages or at least doing some tests and experiment to see if it's beneficial. However, the amount of time it takes to boot shouldn't necessarily be your primary concern.